# ELB and dispatcher

Tags: aem, load-balancing, amazon-elb

Can some explain me how to configure a connection between aem dispatcher and elastic load balancer? Is there any configuration present in the dispatcher to make a connection to ELB

Comment: The dispatcher only connects to the publish instance. I think the configuration you need should be done at the ELB level.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification on this.

Comment: Hello i just wanted to know why do we use ELB when dispatcher can do load balancing